# Sum of series in GP

Tags: summation, proof-writing

$a+ ar+ar^2 + ar^3 +ar^4+ \cdots+ ar^{n-1}=S_n$

$a\left(1+r+r^2 +r^3+\cdots+r^{n-1} \right) = S_n$

Iam trying to get $S_n = \dfrac{a(r^n -1)}{r-1}$

I don't know how to get $1+r+r^2 +r^3+\cdots+r^{n-1}  =\dfrac{r^n -1}{r-1}$

Any help will be appreciated $:)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equation (1)

$S_n = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + …....... +a_n$

Putting value of each term,

Equation (2)

$S_n = a + ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + ar^4 + ... + ar^{n-1}$

Multiply equation (2) by r,

Equation (3)

$rS_n = ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + ar^4 + ........... + ar^{n}$

Subtract equation (2) from (3),

$rS_n - S_n = ar^n - a$

$S_n = \frac{a(r^n - 1)}{r - 1}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $A= 1+r+r^2+...+r^n$, multiply with $r \implies rA=r+r^2+r^3+...+r^{n+1}$. Now, subtract $A-rA=1-r^{n+1} \implies A=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ if $r\neq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\begin{align}S_n-rS_n&=(a+ar+\dots+ar^n)-r(a+ar+\dots+ar^n)\\&=(\color{#4488dd}{a+ar+\dots+ar^n})-(\color{#44dd88}{ar+ar^2+\dots+ar^{n+1}})\\&=\color{#4488dd}a-\color{#44dd88}{ar}+\color{#4488dd}{ar}-\color{#44dd88}{ar^2}+\color{#4488dd}{ar^2}+\dots-\color{#44dd88}{ar^n}+\color{#4488dd}{ar^n}-\color{#44dd88}{ar^{n+1}}\\&=a-ar^{n+1}\end{align}$$

Comment: But it is $^{n+1}$